# Getting error "TypeError: cannot pickle '_cffi_backend.FFI' object" in Python

Tags: python, cffi

this `cffi` library was installed by some dependency, and now it is rising this error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 372, in 
starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in 
get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 537, in 
_handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 211, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_cffi_backend.FFI' object
```

The point of the code where it is rising the error is this:

```
    if parallel_process is True:
        print("Start parallel processing")
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
            boxes = pool.starmap(      <<<----- Here is where the traceback reports the error
                action,
                zip(
                    boxes,
                    repeat(var1),
                    repeat(var2),
                    repeat(var3),
                    repeat(var4),
                ),
            )
```

I made some research, but the only thing a found was this bug correction report, but I don't know how to implement it: https://github.com/mcpyproject/McPy/pull/20

My environment is Windows 10 pro, python 3.10.4, and cffi 1.15.0.

**EDIT**

I found that the error only rises when `parallel_process is True`, otherwise, the pooling is not executed and the error doesn't rise. Summing up, I believe cffi is not compatible with the multiprocessing feature of python.

Does anybody know if this is so?

Comment: Likely not the same issue as OP, but I'm getting the same error while attempting to pickle a CipherContext from pyca/cryptography. Any ideas for that?

Comment: It ended up not being possible because the library object is not pickable. There's no solution but avoiding paralellization

Comment: I have the same issue on MacOS. Running the same code on Debian works. My code was running custom "remote tail" function inside ProcessPoolExecutor and returns list of log records, but when ProcessPoolExecutor is done and I call for executor.results() I have this error message. As a workaround I write log records in file in this "remote tail" function and it returns None and then read records from file. So no executor.results() call and no issue

Comment: @ЛюбомирПавловський I tried your approach but the program just executes successfully without running fully. It just exits without processing fully.